# tempstar furnace the inducer motor runs all the time

Tags: furnace

my inducer motor runs all the time.  what can be wrong  I have replaced the thermostat and the controll board and it still does it.

Comment: Does the furnace fire up?

Comment: The model number could help us look it up. Some motors are controlled locally (close to the motor) with a relay some times the relay contacts weld closed this may be the cause but is a guess.